# MySQL Join to show all rows

Tags: mysql, dump

I have two MySQL tables with the following structure:

```
TABLE `orders`

order_id
order_date
product_id

TABLE `products`

product_id
product_name
product_price
product_type
```

I want to show all rows from table orders and if there is a product_id in TABLE products show all data of that product. If there isn't, show all data from orders table only.

I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM orders AS o RIGHT JOIN products AS p ON o.product_id=p.product_id
```

But if we have a row with a product_id inside orders table that doesn't exist in products table, then the row from orders is not showed. I want the row from orders id to show no matter if there is a product_id inside products table. If there is JOIN it, if it isnt show just the data from table orders.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use LEFT instead of RIGHT :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be doing a `LEFT JOIN`

With a left join, *all* rows from `ORDERS`  will be returned.  The columns from the `products` table will be `null` if the criteria for the `join` is not met.

```
SELECT    o.*,p.* 
FROM      orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN products AS p 
       ON o.product_id=p.product_id`
```

See the [MySQL manual join syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)